# Count the number of characters in a file

Tags: python-3.x

The question:
Write a function `file_size(filename)` that returns a count of the number of characters in the file whose name is given as a parameter. You may assume that when being tested in this CodeRunner question your function will never be called with a non-existent filename.

For example, if `data.txt` is a file containing just the following line: `Hi there!`

A call to `file_size('data.txt')` should return the value `10`. This includes the newline character that will be added to the line when you're creating the file (be sure to hit the 'Enter' key at the end of each line).

What I have tried:

```
def file_size(data):
    """Count the number of characters in a file"""
    infile = open('data.txt')
    data = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    return len(data)
print(file_size('data.txt'))
# data.txt contains 'Hi there!' followed by a new line 
character.
```

I get the correct answer for this file however I fail a test that users a larger/longer file which should have a character count of 81 but I still get 10. I am trying to get the code to count the correct size of any file.

Comment: You always open data.txt ? The filename should be a variable for your tests no? Like `open(filename)` with filename given as argument to your function

Comment: Are you always calling `file_size('data.txt')` or you have just designed the function?

Comment: I see my mistake now, you are correct and I should be calling the function using filename in order to access any file not just the data.txt file. Thankyou